# Sequelize multiple databases, common Model name

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + '/commonmodel')
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3)     === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/commonmodel', file))(db.DB1,         Sequelize.DataTypes, { logging: false });
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + '/commonmodel')
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/commonmodel', file))(db.DB2,     Sequelize.DataTypes, { logging: false });
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

db.commonmodel.create({})
```

How can I specify which Database to use while creating model.

I am trying to use multiple databases with same model name, I successfully connected to and synced to three of them I have a common model name, how am I supposed to specific which Database i am trying to save the model in.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all while defining the model classes you specify a sequelize instance. So just create two different sequelize instances.

```
// src/instances/sequelizeFirstDB

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new Sequelize(process.env.FIRST_DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://postgres:Password@localhost:3205/firstDb'); // Put your connection string here.
```

```
// src/instances/sequelizeSecondDB

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new Sequelize(process.env.SECOND_DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://postgres:Password@localhost:3205/secondDB'); // Put your connection string here.
```

While using init, specify which instance(db) you want.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const { sequelizeInstance } = require('src/instances/sequelizeSecondDB');

class YourModel extends Sequelize.Model { }
YourModel.init({
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
    }
}, { sequelize: sequelizeInstance });

module.exports = YourModel;
```

After that you can import the needed model to query the database.

A side note. Prefer sequelize migrations over sequelize.sync